# Override Separator on Zend_Form Radio Elements When Using a ViewScript Decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-view, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I am using ViewScripts to decorate my form elements.  With radio elements, the separator can normally be overridden, but the override is being ignored when I use the ViewScript.

When I use the below call and ViewScript, the radio elements are separated by a '<br />' rather than the space I've specified.  If leave the default decorators, the override works.

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'active', array(
    'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
    'decorators' => array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'form/multi.phtml'))),
    'label' => 'Active',
    'required' => true,
    'multiOptions' => array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No',),
    'value' => '1',
    'separator' => ' ',
    'filters' => array(),
    'validators' => array(),
));
```

ViewScript:

```
<div class="field <?php echo strtolower(end(explode('_',$this->element->getType()))) ?><?php if($this->element->hasErrors()): ?> errors<?php endif; ?>" id="field_<?php echo $this->element->getId(); ?>">
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getLabel())): ?>
        <?php echo $this->formLabel($this->element->getName(), $this->element->getLabel());?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $this->{$this->element->helper}(
        $this->element->getName(),
        $this->element->getValue(),
        $this->element->getAttribs(),
        $this->element->getMultiOptions()
    ); ?></span>
    <?php if ($this->element->hasErrors()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->formErrors($this->element->getMessages()); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (0 < strlen($this->element->getDescription())): ?>
        <span class="hint"><?php echo $this->element->getDescription(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the view script, this line, $this->{$this->element->helper}(...), runs the functions listed in the [Zend View Helpers documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html).  The function in this case is formRadio().  There is a fifth parameter to formRadio() which is the separator!  Adding the fifth parameter, by referencing the element, solves the problem:

```
<span class="value"><?php echo $this->{$this->element->helper}(
    $this->element->getName(),
    $this->element->getValue(),
    $this->element->getAttribs(),
    $this->element->getMultiOptions(),
    $this->element->getSeparator()
); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem, I've solved by using setting disableLoadDefaultDecorators to `true` and separator to `&nbsp;` or what ever you need.

```
$form->addElement('multiCheckbox', 'myFields', array(
    'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true
    ,'separator'    => '&nbsp;'
    ,'multiOptions' => array(
        'title'       => 'Title'
        ,'first_name' => 'First Name'
        ,'surname'    => 'Surname'
    )
    ,'decorators'   => array(
        'ViewHelper'
        ,'Errors'
        ,array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p'))          
    )
));
```

Comment: Your solution works for your situation, but wouldn't have worked when using a view script. Thanks for posting it though, it may come in handy for someone else trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it can be done in one line:

```
echo $this->element->setSeparator('&nbsp;');
```

Comment: That's the way to set the separator, and it works if you're using the standard decorator. I had a ViewScript decorator that was ignoring the setting. If you look at my solution, you'll see how I solved the problem.