# ul li list with unique id in Zend_Form using decorators

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form

I need to make the following html using Zend form and form decorators...

```
<ul>
        <li id="containeruser1">
                <label for="user1"><input type="checkbox" class="textbox"  value="1" id="user1" name="users[]">User One</label>
        </li>
        <li id="containeruser2">
                <label for="user2"><input type="checkbox" class="textbox"  value="2" id="user2" name="users[]">User Two</label>
        </li>
        <li id="containeruser3">
                <label for="user3"><input type="checkbox" class="textbox"  value="3" id="user3" name="users[]">User Three</label>
        </li>
        <li id="containeruser4">
                <label for="user4"><input type="checkbox" class="textbox"  value="4" id="user4" name="users[]">User Four</label>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The php code i use is ....

```
 $userelement = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox ( 'users' );
                    $userelement-> setRequired(true)
                    ->addDecorator("<li>")
                    ->addMultiOptions ( array ('1' => 'User One', '2' => 'User Two', '3' => 'User Three', '4' => 'User Four' ) )
                    ->setSeparator ( '</li><li>' )->addValidator('NotEmpty', true)
                    ->addErrorMessage('Please select at

least one user');
                $userelement->class = 'textbox';
```

The output is not exactly wht i want.... Each li tag needs to have a unique id so tht i can use some js to do some client side validations and modifications......  Im beginning to use Zend_form and the decorators are a bit confusing ......Please do help...

Answer (score 1):

I have custom ViewScripts for each element type, giving me plenty of styling and scripting hooks.  Here are my posts on that:

- [ViewScripts for File Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143462/how-do-i-use-viewscripts-on-zend-form-file-elements)
- [Recommended Path For Zend Form Element View Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202633/recommended-path-for-zend-form-element-view-scripts)
- [Override Separator on Zend_Form Radio Elements When Using a ViewScript Decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148510/override-separator-on-zend-form-radio-elements-when-using-a-viewscript-decorator)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JS to locate the container. This way you don't have to change the decorators.
jQuery example

```
// example 1
$('#user1').parent().parent().css('color', 'green');

// example 2
$('#user1').parents('li').css('color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox and made a new element instead of using element decorators .... Thanks for all your help...